# I want to replace all matching string which endsWith XYZ to ABC in mongodb using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

```
Document filter = new Document("attribute", new Document("$regex", "XYZ$"));
        Document update = new Document("$set", new Document("attribute",
                new Document("$replaceOne", new Document("input", "$attribute")
                        .append("find", "XYZ")
                        .append("replacement", "ABC"))));

        var result = coll.updateMany(filter, update);
        System.out.println(result.getModifiedCount());
```

The above is setting the attribute to replaceOne object rather than the value. Please let me know my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are doing [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VmGB3qx2YBV) where `update` object does not recognize `$replaceOne` so it is inserted into the object.

Yo need [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Z6D4ulagyl) where the `update` object is an aggregation pipeline. It's almost the same but adding `[]`.

So I've not tested but your `update` value can be something like:

```java
List<Document> update = Arrays.asList(
    new Document("$set", 
        new Document("attribute", 
            new Document("$replaceOne", 
                new Document("input", "$attribute")
                    .append("find", "XYZ")
                    .append("replacement", "ABC")
            )
        )
    )
);
```